# Resuming File Downloads in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, download, resume-download

Finally found out how to achieve this!

Turned out it is as simple as enabling xsendfile and setting header parameter Accept-Range

Read my answer below

(by the way, in the block quote below I wrote a common pitfall newbies - like I did - made. We tend to think it should be manually programmed)

> URL must be something like:
>   mysite.com/get_file?file_point=100 ->
>   this will read from byte 100
>
> 1. Get the offset from parameter (file_point parameter in our example)
> 2. Find out size of file (File.size)
> 3. Read the file from offset to length (Equivalent of fseek in PHP)
> 4. Send the file using send_file
>
> I dont know how to do step #3 in Ruby
>   in the steps above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was how I did it:

```
response.header["Accept-Ranges"] = "bytes"
send_file product.pack.path, :type => product.pack_content_type, :x_sendfile=>true
```

I asked our server guy to set up mod_xsendfile, I don't know how to set it myself.

Tutorial here: http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Techniques/Resumable-File-Downloads-with-ASPNet/2/

Read about content-length here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13

About streaming is available here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html